# Bootstrap 4 Internet Explorer missing column wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

As per title I am using Bootstrap 4 and I can reproduce even on a simple row-col configuration a problem with Internet Explorer: the column wrap does not apply.

While in chrome with a small screen all the elements fit nicely in the viewport, in Explorer they get trimmed instead of wrapping as supposed to be.

```
<div class="container root">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-auto logo">
          <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar?d=mm&s=60" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col title">
          Extralongword supermegagiga
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col">
            <select class="form-control-sm" name="" id="">
              <option value="">Please choose...</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">+</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <select class="form-control-sm" name="" id="">
              <option value="">Please choose...</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is clear checking this Codepen:
https://codepen.io/stilllife00/pen/VyOMBX

It is probably a misbehavior of Explorer with flexbox but I assume bootstrap should cover this cross-browser issues.

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing? It looks the same for me in chrome and IE11.

Comment: @TidyDev 11.125.16299.0, the difference appears on small screens, when the components should wrap instead they crop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in changing `col` by `col-sm` :

```
<div class="container root">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm"> <-- HERE 2nd Update
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-auto logo">
          <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar?d=mm&s=60" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col title">
          Extralongword supermegagiga
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <select class="form-control-sm" name="" id="">
              <option value="">Please choose...</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">+</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <select class="form-control-sm" name="" id="">
              <option value="">Please choose...</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJEjpg

Comment: It is slightly better but it does not solve the problem.
You can see here https://codepen.io/stilllife00/pen/rpgvrg the title gets chopped on small screens

Comment: It seems to disappear when you add the same col-sm class to your title (see update)

Comment: I am not sure to which update you are referring to. I tried to put `col-sm` in the `.title` div but it still doesn't help. Here a comparison: https://snag.gy/UHDver.jpg

Moreover col-sm is just working based on media queries, what I am investigating here is if there is an actual bug on Bootstrap side regarding explorer. It should wrap properly as per flexbox specs as Chrome does (given a proper CSS). col-sm is just a way to force the wrap on certain viewport sizes

Comment: Nope, I tagged with second update my html code, and gave a link

Comment: Ok I am gonna accept the answer since it results in a proper wrap.I am still not 100% happy though cause we are just forcing the wrap by media queries and not using the flex-wrap by specs.

Comment: But after the doc https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width, I can read that the 'col' are just when all sizes are divided the same way, and have to use the col-sm in the chapter before https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works